# Number of columns in query = 1, Number of columns in table = 2

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, windows

I am attempting to insert an int value in a table (RamResults) on a database, the db structure is as follows:

Table Columns:
ID (Primary Key)
Results (int type)

In C# I attempt to insert a value into the Results column:

```
// Retrieve the connection string from the settings file.
string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.MyDBConnectionString;

// Open the connection using the connection string.
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
{
    con.Open();

    // Insert into the SqlCe table. ExecuteNonQuery is best for inserts.
    int num = 5;
    using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand(
                              "INSERT INTO RamResults VALUES(@num)", con))
    {
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", num);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> The number of columns in the query and the table must match. [ Number
>   of columns in query = 1, Number of columns in table = 2 ]

I was under the impression that the primary key (ID) did not need any data inserted into it, as it would automatically assign an ID number in that column?

**Edit:**

Assuming that I need to autoincrement the PK, I can't see how to do this when editing the table schema in VS 2010:

[image]

Comment: Well automatically in case its identity column, what are the setails of the column can you add them here

Comment: Primary key means unique, not auto generated.

Comment: "Primary Key" is not enough, it also has to be set to auto-increment (Identity). Post the table-definition and the _exact_ error.

Comment: @Mike: it will do automatically if the `ID` column has `Autoincrement`

Comment: @Tigran Please see my revised question, I can't see how to do this in the table schema

Comment: @Mike - You need to choose `int` datatype as you say you want a number. `uniqueidentifier` is for GUIDs. Then you should see options for setting the `IDENTITY` specification. You will have to drop this column and create a new one as you can't convert from guid to int.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I have done as you said, but it throws the message: The number of columns in the query and the table must match. [ Number of columns in query = 1, Number of columns in table = 2 ] I have a new column - "ID" (deleted the old one) using int type and set as indentity type incrementing in 1's and its marked as a PK and the other remains the same called Results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case **seemes to that ID is not IDENTITY** autoincrementing value and you should specify its value explicitly

```
INSERT INTO RamResults(Id, Results) VALUES(@Id, @num)
```

and you, of course, should provide the @id parameter's value manually

**OR**

Should place the `DEFAULT` to the Id column, in your case - or `NEWID()` or `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`

In this case your query should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO RamResults(Id, Results) VALUES(DEFAULT, @num)
```

**OR** without `DEFAULT` constraint:

```
INSERT INTO RamResults(Id, Results) VALUES(NEWID(), @num)
```

Comment: Please see revised post, I would like to have the ID automatically increment

Comment: Except they say they want an auto incrementing number so doesn't seem they are using the correct datatype anyway.

Comment: In sql 2008 there is an autoincremental ability to uniqueidentifier field - the NEWSEQUENTIALID() function, but if they mean - autoincremental and ORDINAL(NUMERIC) - then they are wrong with choosen datatype

Answer (score 2):

the `ID` which is your primary key **does not** automatically insert a value unless you set it to AutoIncrement.

**UPDATE**

based on the schema, the data type of your `ID` is **UniqueIdentifier**, try changing it to **Integer** or **Int** so that you can set `Is Identity` to **True**

Answer (score 1):

that's exactly right. your message is telling you that the pk is not automagically generated.

Look up [Identity columns](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/understanding-identity-columns). Either create an automatic one or supply a value.

Answer (score 1):

Specify Columns in INSERT query

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Reference: 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: This helped me for SqlCe database.

Answer (score 1):

Set your ID column to "Identity" in the table designer. That will do the trick and insert an incremental ID automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to insert primekey (Id) column value only when its `identity`. And it isn't by default.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you explicitely specify the columns?

```
INSERT INTO RamResults
(Results)
VALUES (@num)
```

Comment: They will need to specify the value for the PK unless it is an `IDENTITY` and if it was an `IDENTITY` the original code would work as an `INSERT` without a column list is assumed not to include the identity column.

Answer (score 0):

```
Do not specify the column Id if it is primary key and Identity is true, then it will work fine
private void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("insert into Result(Name,RollNo,Age,Trade,Marks) values(@name,@rollno,@age,@trade,@marks)", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name_txt.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rollno", roll_txt.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", age_txt.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trade", trade_txt.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@marks", marks_txt.Text);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Submitted");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Number of columns in query = 1, Number of columns in table = 2 if u want to pass the result parameter to your query you have to auto Increment the Id field in DB and also change the type of ID to int

**Suggestion**
I suggest you to use Entity Framework and Use Store Procedure for query the data base rather you type the code in C# while you are using Store Procedure its enhance your application security and reuse ability of your code. Also you have option to use simple Linq Query to access data base and call simple add method to add.